# How can I initialize an std::vector of std::map items?

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, vector, stl

I have the following:

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::map<std::string, double>> data = {{"close", 14.4}, {"close", 15.6}};

    return 0;
}
```

And when I try to compile, I get the following error:

> g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic ./test.cpp
>
> ./test.cpp:6:49: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::vector >' (aka
>         'vector, allocator >, double> >')
>       std::vector> data = {{"close", 14.4}, {"close", 15.6}};

Comment: Try to think of std::map as a list of std::pairs, try this: `{ { {"close", 14.4} }, { {"close", 15.6} } }`. A vector of 2 maps, each with 1 pair.

Comment: @Chad Answers belong in the answer box, not as comments.

Comment: @Barry Fully fleshed out answers belong in the answer box. I didn't feel like writing a good answer, so I wrote a comment.

Comment: @Chad If you don't feel like writing an answer, just don't. Don't take this half-step in between where you actually answer the question but just in the wrong place.

Comment: @Barry I disagree, comments like "have you tried" are valuable, and I will continue to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need an extra pair of braces for each element/pair:

```
std::vector<std::map<std::string, double>> data = {{{"close", 14.4}}, {{"close", 15.6}}};
                                                    ^             ^    ^             ^
```

The extra pair of braces is needed because `std::map` elements are of type `std::pair<const key_type, value_type>` in your case `std::pair<const std::string, double>`. Thus, you need an extra pair of braces to signify to the compiler the initialization of the `std::pair` elements.

Answer (score 5):

Use 3 braces instead of 2.

```
std::vector<std::map<std::string, double>> data = {{{"close", 14.4}}, {{"close", 15.6}}};
```

Its what chad said.